# Find out efficient sequence

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am looking for a algorithm that can help me to find out the best way to assign the task to my team.
So here is the problem.
I have n team members (For example n=2) and I have to complete m task (for example m=4) and for every task every team member have their capacity to complete in time. Let say

[image]

One condition:  the task can only be assigned continuously and output should be the minimum efforts.
in above example output would be 8. Either assign task1 & task2 to member1 and task3 & task4 to member2.
OR task1 to member1 and rest to member2 OR all the task to member2.

I know the stackoverflow helps developer to resolve the error but i don't understand how to build logic for the above problem.
Thanks in advance for suggestion of any algorithm to resolve this problem.

[image]

output: 6

Comment: What's more to do than going from row 0 to row n and pick always the column with the lowest value?

Comment: For better understanding i have added 1 more image. If i assign the lowest one than in consecutive assignment result will be 1 + (1+3+2) = 7

Comment: Second example should have output: 5.  task1:member2, task2:member1, task3:member 2, task4:member2: 1+1+2+1=5.

Comment: To be clear: members CANNOT work at the same time?

Comment: Go through Tasks and assign to member who can do it faster.  If a draw, perhaps store separately, and after all no-draw tasks have been assigned, distribute remaining tasks evenly such that each member spends about the same time.

Comment: member can work same time but not on same task. For second example output will not be 5 as we can assign the task to any member only continuously. if we start assign tak to member 2 we can not re assign task to member1.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of this problem is that we have a list of members, a list of tasks, and each member has a cost for each task.  Starting at the beginning of the tasks we assign some to member 1, then the next block to member 2, then the next block to member 3 and so on.  The order is fixed.

We are trying to minimize which member takes the longest.

Is that true?

If so then I recommend doing a binary search for the length of time that the longest member takes.  Any time you don't complete everything in time, you have to increase the amount of time.  Any time you complete everything, you decrease.  The twist is that you need to keep track of what time period you would have made different choices at.

The heart of the algorithm is a function like this pseudocode:

```
try_time_period(members, costs, max_cost_per_member):
    min_same_result = min_change_result = max_cost_per_member
    i = 0
    for each member:
        cost = 0
        while cost < max_cost_per_member:
            this_cost = cost[member][i]
            if max_cost_per_member <= cost + this_cost:
                cost += this_cost
                i++
                if len(costs[member]) <= i:
                    return (True, min_same_result, min_change_result)
            else:
                if cost < min_same_result:
                    min_same_result = cost
                if min_change_result < cost + this_cost:
                    min_change_result = cost + this_cost
                next member
    return (False, min_same_result, min_change_result)
```

And with that, we can build a binary search for the `max_cost_per_member`.

```
lower = 0
upper = time for first member to do everything
while lower < upper:
    mid = (lower + upper)/2
    (success, min_same_result, min_change_result) = try_time_period(members, costs, mid)
    if success:
        upper = min_same_result
    else:
        lower = min_change_result
```

And they will converge at the lowest time for completing everything from your assignments.  Now you just work out the previous solution for that, and you're done.